# Creating styled map and exporting it?

Tags: qgis

Is there any way to create a styled map using a .json file from something like maputnik and export the map as a PDF or high resolution .png?

I currently have QGIS, maperitive, and tilemill, but I don't see any way to style these with the .json file.

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS SE! Please take the [tour] and improve your question with further content and what you already have tried.